# Nginx - Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Reverse Proxy to Remote Site

Tags: http, nginx, https, reverse-proxy, http-redirect

I'm really looking for a kind of a hint in solving a problem with nginx reverse proxy.
Right now I have a config silimar to this:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.net;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/example.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/example.key;

  location / {

     resolver 1.1.1.1 ipv6=off;
     proxy_ssl_server_name on;
     proxy_pass https://<example.com>:443;
  }
}
```

So basically this configuration makes this: you type `https://example.net` into your browser and you get the contents of `https://example.com` in response, but the initial domain stays the same (*example.net*).

As a finish move I want to make an HTTP to HTTPS redirect while accessing example.net. Let me explain: like you type only `example.net` into your browser and it automatically responses back to you with `https://example.net` contents, but the domain stays the same (example.net).

I tried the following approach:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.net;

  return 301 https://example.com:443$request_uri;
```

}

I also tried `proxy_pass` directive and changed `example.com` to `example.net` in permanent redirect directive. None of it seems to work properly.

While investigating developers console in Chrome browser I get `NS_BINDING_ABORTED` which typically says that the initial request was modified before being finished.

So guys, let me know where I'm mistaken. Is it real to make it work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want automatic redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. For that your Nginx config file should look like following.

```
    server {
            if ($host = example.net) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            }
        
          server_name example.net;
          listen 80;
        }

    server {
          listen 443 ssl http2;
          server_name example.net;
    
          ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/example.crt;
          ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/example.key;
    
        location / {
    
          resolver 1.1.1.1 ipv6=off;
          proxy_ssl_server_name on;
          proxy_pass https://<example.com>;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! When I tested it, it showed me NS_ERROR_NET_TIMEOUT error while accessing example.net via http. We're closer to solving the problem

Comment: Hi i think nginx is serving fine but it is not able to proxy pass example.com.Can you check it if you are able to **curl https://example.com** from your host.It will be better if you can send me nginx access log when you are getting NS_ERROR_NET_TIMEOUT

Comment: Thanks! The trick is that I don't even see those requests in access log when I try to go to```http://example.net```. The only facts that are fixed here is when I access ```https://example.net``` directly. And also there are no errors in error.log. I just don't understand where my requests go.. But DNS lookups example.net correctly on the hosts

Comment: So guys! The initial reason was due to port 80 being blocked by the firewall rule on AWS. I'm so sorry for losing your time. This is the right approach to redirecting http traffic! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since your server block listening on 443 is expecting `example.net`, you need to redirect to `example.net` instead of `example.com`. The ports can be omitted, because you use the default ports.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.net;
  return 301 https://example.net$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will change your url

return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

```
    server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.net;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/example.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/example.key;

  location / {

     resolver 1.1.1.1 ipv6=off;
     proxy_ssl_server_name on;
     proxy_pass https://example.com:443;
     return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
  }
}
```